# doubled Info while using F12 tool

Tags: php, html, css, web

Hey When Im using site editor. F12 TOOL in chrome or firefox or W/E I get doubled info.

Like this:

http://pressyou.com/images/screenshot.jpg

there is a something wrong in my website? or only on my computer?

I need your help thanks!!

Comment: Have you included your style.css twice?

Comment: LOL,I made a page and included it into other pages,thats made double called of CSS

thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things, your `CSS` file is being called in twice. Go to the network tab and reload your page. It will show each file thats being loaded in.

If it is finding a second `CSS` style being loaded in, check your code to see if your calling the file twice.

Comment: LOL,I made a page and included it into other pages,thats made double called of CSS

thanks guys!!!